# How to copy BS character (0x08) to input for buffer overflow in GDB?

Tags: linux, exploit, bash, debug

I need to overflow a buffer with a specific value that contains 0x08. If I use `echo -ne "AA\x08A"`, the output is `AA`, as the backspace character and one A are removed.

How do I copy this value into the input of my vulnerable program? I would like it to be in GBD, so I can inspect the stack afterwards.

Comment: Note that this is not actually a security question since all you care about is outputting some characters. It does not matter at all for your question that you want to feed these characters into a vulnerable program.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, I know. I didn't know a better site for this. I thought that people here know this, as they used it in the past

Answer (score 1):

> If I use echo -ne "AA\x08A", the output is AA, as the backspace character and one A are removed.

It only looks like this because you print the output to the terminal and backspace has a special meaning in this case: delete the previous character similar to what you achieve when you press the backspace key on the keybaord. This means it will display the first A, the second A, delete the second A and go back after the first A and display the 4th character, i.e. A:

```
 $ echo -ne "AA\x08A"
 AA
```

But in reality it will print all 4 octets - as a display with `hd` (or `hexdump` or `xxd`...) will show:

```
 $ echo -ne "AA\x08A" | hd
 00000000  41 41 08 41                      |AA.A|
```

And the same 4 characters will also be printed to any other program, like your vulnerable one or some perl script:

```
$ echo -ne "AA\x08A" | perl -e 'print unpack("H*",<STDIN>),"\n"'
41410841
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try loading the input from a file in a second. That might solve the problem